# running sahi inside cruisecontrol

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, sahi

How to run sahi inside cruisecontrol? I'm a bit confused here, because some of the steps needed to do on running sahi is choosing the browser I would like to use for the test and pressing `alt+double click`... Is there any clue for me? Example on `ccnet.config` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick study, I can see that Cruise Control supports ANT. You can invoke sahi scripts using ANT targets. You need not open a browser and press alt+double click, Sahi can run scripts from command line using test runner also. For a detailed not on this, please look at: http://sahi.co.in/w/Running+multiple+tests+in+batch+mode.

I have not seen ccnet.config, but if you can invoke ANT targets, then this integration with jenkins will give you important pointers: http://sahi.co.in/w/integrate-with-jenkins

Thanks,
Vivek